# AWS vpc access the Internet from public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, vpc

I configured public subnet on my VPC and add some Security Groups and NACL roles... I notice that when I set on NACL these roles in the inbound section :

```
100 SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
200 HTTP (80) TCP (6) 80 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
300 HTTPS (443) TCP (6) 4430.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
```

I didn't got access to the internet !!! :(

unless I added this role in the inbound section:
400 ALLTraffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

(after adding this role, I succeeded to get internet access by running "yum update" for example...)

It is really necessary or I configured somethings wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Security Groups are **stateful** and automatically allow return traffic.
- Network ACLs are **stateless** and require you to provide inbound rules.

This is why you could get access to the internet once you added the `400 ALLOW` Network ACL rule.

Depending on your requirements, you may not need Network ACLs at all instead relying on the Security Groups alone.

--

AWS VPC Security Groups and Network ACLs have different but complementary behavior.

This documentation describes the difference in detail.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html#VPC_Security_Comparison

Comment: If this is the reason, why Amazon attempting to recommend some roles for public subnet on this documentation without the 400 all traffic allow (on scenario 2) : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html

Comment: The key phrase in the opening paragraph of the link you cited was "**If you need an additional layer of security, you can create a network ACL and add rules.**" So, if the protection that Security Groups provide at the instance level is not sufficient, Network ACLs allow you to further define subnet level protections. However, doing so means it is up to you to define exactly which ports you want to allow.  If the hosts you are protecting need to communicate with the internet at large, I'd argue that the scenario requirements aren't so stringent that Security Groups alone wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your time.